# Lazarus: i18n doesn't translate the application

Tags: internationalization, lazarus, freepascal, po, poedit

I've programmed a Lazarus application in German and now I want to translate it into English. So I activated i18n in the project settings and checked "update .po file...". Then, I created a unit `uTranslationStrings` and put `resourcestring example = 'Beispiel';` before `implementation`. I made sure to `use` `uTranslationStrings, DefaultTranslator, LCLTranslator` in my main unit. Then, I ran the application and opened the `projectXY.po` file in Poedit. I translated everything into English and saved it as `projectXY.en.po`. I did the same thing for the German locale. Also, I added a language menu entry letting the user switch between German and English.

```
procedure TMainForm.MenuDeutschClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetDefaultLang('de');
end;

procedure TMainForm.MenuEnglischClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetDefaultLang('en');
end;
```

But when I try to actually switch the languages, nothing happens. I thought the reason could be that all the translation strings are just captions of labels so I added the following code in `uMain`:

```
Application.MessageBox(PChar(i18nWarning),PChar(i18nError),MB_ICONERROR);
```

and the following code in `uTranslationStrings`:

```
resourcestring
  // other strings
  i18nWarning = 'Warnung! Deine Eingabe ist inkorrekt!';
  i18nError = 'Fehler';
```

but the `MessageBox` is always displayed in German even if I start my program with `program.exe --lang en` (but note that the German text ***is*** displayed).

Why is that and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I "solved" the problem: I completely deleted the i18n and did everything again (in the exact same way). For some reason, it does work now.